# Automatic drawing with sketch.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using sketch.js for a project to draw on a canvas. There is a case where I need to do an automatic drawing: that is, I need a way to feed two sets of coordinates-one for where to move to, the other to where to draw to-and have sketch.js to draw the resulting line. Any ideas? I think that startPainting() is a place to start, but I am at a loss on how to send the coordinates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch.js stores all drawing actions which happens on the canvas in a variable called actions.

So you can initialize an action by hand and add this to the array and redraw the sketch.

example function:

```
function drawLine(xFrom, yFrom, xTo, yTo) {
     //get the sketch instance - assumes that your canvas has an id 'simple_sketch'
     var s =  $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
     //initialize the draw action
     var action = {
         color: "#000000",
         events: [{event: 'mousedown', x: xFrom, y: yFrom}, {event: 'mouseup', x: xTo, y:yTo}],
         size: 5,
         tool: "marker"
     };
     //push it to the actions array
     s.actions.push(action);
     //redraw the sketch
     s.redraw();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wound up going with something else, but this was an interesting solution to the problem. :)